# Query number of edges to each connected vertex

Tags: gremlin

I have a dataset with several orders and their respective purchases (called products). The orders are linked to the products they purchased. For a given product P1, I would like to get a list of all "linked" products (i.e. products that were purchased in the same orders as P1) with the number of occurrences (i.e. the number of orders that purchased those "linked" products)

In gremlin, I have already constructed a graph connecting all orders to their respective purchases. I am using Cosmos DB in case that is important. I am able to query all orders that purchased P1:

```
g.V().hasLabel('PRODUCT').has('id', '2').in('purchased')
```

I am also able to query all linked products:

```
g.V().hasLabel('PRODUCT').has('id','2').in('purchased').out('purchased')
```

However, the first query only returns the orders that purchased P1, and the second only returns the "linked" products. I am unable to get the number of occurrences of each "linked" product. Does anyone have any advice? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a classic recommendation query. Basically, you're only missing the final step:

```
g.V().has('PRODUCT','id','2').
  in('purchased').
  out('purchased').
  groupCount()
```

However, you probably don't want to include the initial product in your result:

```
g.V().has('PRODUCT','id','2').as('a').
  in('purchased').
  out('purchased').
    where(neq('a')).
  groupCount()
```